# how to automatically make a cell pick the item with the highest value and replace the others in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, array-formulas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7A7Q.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QyC4.png)I have a google sheet that I share with other users and it consists of Colum A1 to A5 has the name of the users, Colum B1:B5 has a drop-down list with the tools we share and  Colum C1:C5 have the hours that the tool was used for used.  on Colum Y, I have the list of all the tools and on Colum Z I have the total hours used. I will like to make it to when I change the drop-down list to another tool to update the total hours on Colum Z or use a push Button to match the tool name to the user and add the hours that the user added to it.

Comment: It could be much more easy to read and solve if you share a sample spreadsheet!

Comment: coud you please explain how to share it? i been trying but i cant find a way to upload it.

Comment: You don't need to upload it just share it to public and provide the link.  You may wish to copy it first and remove private information

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart < 6 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.oldValue) {
    e.source.toast('Flag1')
    let toollist = sh.getRange(1,25,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
    let r = toollist.indexOf(e.oldValue) + 1;
    let hrs = sh.getRange(3,e.range.columnStart).getValue();
    sh.getRange(r,26).setValue(sh.getRange(r,26).getValue() + hrs);
    sh.getRange(3,e.range.columnStart).setValue('');
  }
}
```

Layout of Sheet0

[image]

You will probably want to change the sheet name